# Trouble with break statement in While loop

Tags: while-loop, break, python-3.3

I'm trying to write a program that collects information from the user, then outputs to a text file. The program collects input correctly, as the print statement I inserted tells me, but the break statement doesn't break the loop when the specified value is input, and the output file is never updated. Any suggestions you could give would really help. Thanks!

```
# 1. Define Greeting:
def greeting():
    print("Welcome, user! Please enter the address data, or type 'quit'.")

# 2. Input
def inputData():
    name = input("Enter the name: ")
    address = input("Enter the address: ")
    city = input("Enter the city: ")
    state = input("Enter the state: ")
    zipCode = input("Enter the zip: ")
    phone = input("Enter the phone number: ")
    addressData = str(name + ", " + address + ", " +
                       city + ", " + state + ", "+ zipCode +
                       ", " + phone)
    print(addressData)
    return(name)

# 3. Write data to text file
def dataWrite():
    f.write(addressData + "\n")

# 4. Display the goodbye message:
def goodbye():
    print("Have a nice day!")

# 5. Define Main function:
def main():    
    greeting()
    while name != "quit":
         inputData()
         if name == "quit":
             break
         else:
             dataWrite()
    f.close()        
    goodbye()
main()
```

Comment: What is `f`? You don't define it anywhere. In your `main` function, `name` is not defined - you need to call the `inputData()` method _before_ your while loop, and then save its return value. So you need `name = inputData()`, then you can do `while name != 'quit':` and then don't forget inside your while you also need `name = inputData()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():    
    greeting()
    while name != "quit":
         name = inputData()
         if name == "quit":
             break
         else:
             dataWrite()
    f.close()        
    goodbye()
```

You are not getting the return value of `inputData()`.